# PDF document which was initially converted from a Tiff image loses it's quality after compression using Pdftron

Tags: c#-4.0, pdftron

I am trying to generate a pdf out of byte array and then try to compress it. The initial document is a tiff image. Then that tiff is converted to a pdf and then I am trying to compress that pdf. I am using Pdftron to compress it. For some tiff images the compression is fine while for other the converted pdf looks faded,scrambled and unreadable.My code is as given below:

To optimize the converted pdf:

```
private void OptimizePdf(string path)
    {


        var documentBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(path);

        var request = new ConvertDocumentRequest();
        var response = new ConvertDocumentResponse();

        request.Document = documentBytes;
        request.ConversionType = PdfConversionType.PdfToOptimizedPdf;
        using (var proxy = _dynamicProxyFactory.Create<Services.PdfModification.Interfaces.IPdfModificationService>())
        {
            response = proxy.Invoke(x => x.ConvertDocument(request));

        }
        File.WriteAllBytes(path, response.Document);         
    }
```

The code for CovertDocument is given below:

```
internal sealed class PdfToOptimizedPdfCommand : IConversionCommand
{
    private readonly IConvertDocumentCriteria _criteria;

    private const double MaxDpi = 144;
    private const double ResamplingDpi = 96;
    private const int ImageQuality = 1;
    private const bool ForceCompression = true;

    public PdfToOptimizedPdfCommand(IConvertDocumentCriteria criteria)
    {
        _criteria = criteria;
    }

    public byte[] Convert()
    {
        var doc = new PDFDoc(_criteria.Document, _criteria.Document.Length);

        var settings = new Optimizer.OptimizerSettings();

        var imageSettings = new Optimizer.ImageSettings();
        imageSettings.SetImageDPI(MaxDpi, ResamplingDpi);
        imageSettings.SetQuality(ImageQuality);
        imageSettings.ForceRecompression(ForceCompression);

        settings.SetColorImageSettings(imageSettings);

        Optimizer.Optimize(doc, settings);

        return doc.Save(SDFDoc.SaveOptions.e_remove_unused | SDFDoc.SaveOptions.e_linearized | SDFDoc.SaveOptions.e_omit_xref);
    }
```

I tried to change the values of MaxDpi,ImageQuality etc, but nothing helped.
So I need some help on this issue.
[image]

Comment: What version of PDFNet are you using? You can call PDFNet.GetVersion() to find out. Also, if the issue is file specific, can you post one of the problem TIFF files?

Comment: The version number is 5.8.0.0. Due to security reasons I cannot post the pdf here. to describe it, it looks a certificate or car title with shaded borders.

Answer (score 0):

Since you cannot post the problematic file, and 5.8.0.0 was released in 2012, I would [download the latest SDK](https://www.pdftron.com/pdfnet/downloads.html) and modify one of the sample projects to reproduce the issue. Most likely it is fixed, in which case you will need to update PDFNet versions.

Comment: I downloaded the latest version, but I still get the same result. I posted how my converted pdf looks like, can you please figure out what's wrong.

Comment: If the issue is file specific, then you need to send it to pdftron support. Send the TIFF, source PDF, and generated/compressed PDF.